# Permission denied when using SPARK dataframes' method "saveAsTable"

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, kerberos, apache-spark-sql

I´m using Spark 1.3 and I´m trying to generate a table from one RDD. This is the pseudo-code:

```
val sc = new org.apache.spark.SparkContext(conf)
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
import sqlContext.implicits._

val rdd1=sc.textFile(path_1).map(........) // RDD[(string,Double)]
val rdd2=sc.textFile(path_2).map(........) // RDD[(string,Double)]
val rdd_join=rdd1.fullOuterJoin(rdd2)      // RDD[String,(Option(Double),Option(Double))) 
val rdd_get = rdd_join.map(....}           // RDD[(String,Double,Double)]
rdd_get.toDF().saveAsTable("database.tablename")
```

When running this code I´m getting the permissions error:

org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=XXXXXXXX, access=WRITE, inode="/user/hive/warehouse":hive:hive:drwxrwx--x:user:hive:rwx,group::---,group:hive:rwx

If I create the table as:

```
  rdd_get.toDF().registerTempTable("rdd_get_temp")
  sqlContext.sql("CREATE TABLE database.tablename AS SELECT * FROM rdd_get_temp")
```

Then It works and creates the table. It looks like saveAsTable() is trying to use my user to write into "/user/hive/warehouse" (this is forbiden by Kerberization) while, sqlContext.sql uses properly user "hive" to do it.

Am I right?? Is this a bug?? Does it work in newer spark versions?

Thanks all.

Comment: Not a bug. If you want "clean" authorization settings, you can set up HiveServer2 to use your actual user account instead of `hive` service account. But then you have to manage ACLs on each HDFS directory used by a Hive table -- just like you would do for a network drive (per user, per group, etc). This generic `hive` account is a very lame thing -- and Sentry / Ranger are just ridiculous band-aids to give an illusion of security to corporate suckers.

Comment: Anyway, if you can get admin privileges (e.g. get a Kerberos ticket as `hdfs`) then you can create an ACL on the directory that you want Spark to create files into, so that *your* user gets write privs. Sthg like `hdfs dfs -setfacl -m user:johndoe:r-x  /user/hive/warehouse/` then `hdfs dfs -setfacl -m user:johndoe:rwx  /user/hive/warehouse/sometable/`

Comment: ...plus a "default" ACL if you need to create partitiions i.e. subdirectories.

Answer (score 0):

SaveAsTable creates a physical table while registerTempTable creates a (temporary) table in memory.
You are right, user needs proper permissions to create physical tables.